# Why can't I declare dynamic variable inside protocol

Tags: swift, dynamic, swift-protocols

I'm currently working on protocols for my objects which inherits from Realm's `Object`. Inside my objects I have variables and these variables are marked as `@objc dynamic`

```
@objc dynamic var title: String = ""
```

Now imagine situation that I have more similar objects with same variable `title`. I want to create protocol for them since I want to have just one generics method for changing title of object.

So, I created protocol with `title` variable marked as `@objc dynamic` with the expectation that this is how it works

```
protocol Titleable: class {
    @objc dynamic var title: String { get set }
}
```

... this didn't work out and I received actually two errors.

One about marking variable as `@objc`

> @objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes

... this I could solve by marking protocol as `@objc`.

However I still had error connected with `dynamic` keyword

> Only members of classes may be dynamic

... I thought that when I constrained protocol for classes, it should be alright, but... it wasn't.

I somehow solved it by removing `@objc` as well as `dynamic` keywords

```
protocol Titleable: class {
    var title: String { get set }
}
```

... that works. I'm able to mark variable as `@objc dynamic` in class where I implement this protocol.

```
class Item: Object, Titleable {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
}
```

However, I'm not sure why this works and why marking variable as `dynamic` inside protocol declaration doesn't. I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: The docs say "Because declarations marked with the dynamic modifier are dispatched using the Objective-C runtime, they must be marked with the objc attribute." Is that not currently true (I haven't tried this in a while.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what `dynamic` [means](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html):

> dynamic
>
> Apply this modifier to any member of a class that can be represented
>   by Objective-C. When you mark a member declaration with the dynamic
>   modifier, access to that member is always dynamically dispatched using
>   the Objective-C runtime. Access to that member is never inlined or
>   devirtualized by the compiler.
>
> Because declarations marked with the dynamic modifier are dispatched
>   using the Objective-C runtime, they must be marked with the objc
>   attribute.

Particularly consider that first paragraph. It says that something that is marked `dynamic` cannot be statically dispatched. Now consider the case where I have some class in a module. It's already been compiled, and its methods were statically dispatched. Now consider another module that conforms that class to some protocol that includes a `dynamic` method. How can that work? The method has *already* been statically dispatched in some places. It can't retroactively be transformed into dynamic dispatch. (The same can apply to declarations in the same module depending on compiler flags and access levels, but I find it easier to explain cross-module.)

The main reason you'd want to do this in any case is to make sure you can use KVO on that property. (If you have some other reason you need to force conforming types to use a dynamic property, I'm interested to know the use case.) If that is your goal, I would probably require `Titleable` to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: Thank you for response and explanation. Reason why I was trying to do it this way was because I saw `@objc dynamic` before my variable inside my class and I said to myself that it had to be in declaration of variable inside protocol too. So after your explanation I hope that I have better view why this is how it is. Also thank you for suggestion with condition that my protocol has to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: So if I understand it right, I can't use any *Declaration modifier* before any variable/method inside Swift protocol declaration, right?

Comment: That's not true. You can, for instance, include `static` and `@objc optional`. There's no general rule against declaration modifiers in protocols; there are just some modifiers that don't apply.

Comment: Oh, right. That's true. So there are some modifiers which can be declared in protocols and some which can't. And this `dynamic` can't be because of reason which your wrote above.